# SVG is not clicable in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Map area is not clickable in ie, I tried lot of solution but still no luck, any help would be really appreciate js [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krux0Ljf/2/embedded/result,css,html,js)

```
<code>[https://jsfiddle.net/krux0Ljf/2/embedded/result,css,html,js][1]</code>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Array.from()`, which is not supported by Internet Explorer.  Use another method to loop through the elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `addEventListener` method which is not implement in IE <9 ([see this MDN documentation snippet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent))

Comment: but I am trying on ie11

Answer (score 0):

addEventListner not supported in the older versions of IE. Older versions of IE supported an equivalent, proprietary .attachEvent() method.

you can modify your script like this :

```
    Array.from(objects).forEach(function(element) {
      addEvent('mouseenter',element, function() {
            TweenLite.to(element, 0.1, {
                fill: "#0a6fac"
            });
      });
   });


function addEvent(evnt, elem, func) {
   if (elem.addEventListener)  // W3C DOM
           elem.addEventListener(evnt,func,false);
   else if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
        elem.attachEvent("on"+evnt, func);
   }
   else { // No much to do
        elem["on"+evnt] = func;
   }
}
```